# Change the position of fields in new address option of magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, fieldsets, reorder

Can anyone please suggest, how to reorder the fields in the Overview and payment page, while adding a new billing and shipping address. Please refer the image below.

[image: Reference image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Change the sortOrder of items in checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<item name="city" xsi:type="array">
 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">115</item>
 <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.city</item>       
 <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>       
</item>
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">                                                                                
    <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->                                                                            
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>                    
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.postcode</item>                               
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">114</item>                         
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
</item>
```

Comment: Is there anything else to do except this code change in the "vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout" checkout_cart_index.xml file . because i still don't see any change in the order. I have n even "Flush Magento Cache and  Flush Cache Storage". Opened the website in the private browser.

Comment: What **sortOrder** value  should i use?